# Unable to find result on ejs template when i passed json array to ejs template

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Pplease help how can i print the results of every user on ejs template.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var resultArray=[];
    mongo.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        var cursor = db.collection('user-data').find();
        cursor.forEach(function (err, data) {
            assert(err, null);
            resultArray.push(data);
        },function () {
            db.close();
            res.render('user-details', { items: resultArray, title:'User Details' });
        });
    });
 });
```

This code is used to send json array i am able to find the length of array but unable to print results.

Comment: If you are connecting and closing database connections on every request, then that really is a bigger problem that you "should" instead be putting priority on fixing. Database connections are meant to "persist" for the life-cycle of your application and are very costly to connect and disconnect on a continual basis. Also there is a [`.toArray()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#toArray) method that does exactly what you are forcing iteration to do.

Comment: could you tell me how can i access on ejs template